# Synchronization of 2 threads, how to?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to develop a C++ software which has 1 thread as controller (say controller) and 8 other threads (child threads) will do send/recv via TCP/IP.

My software is operated in loops:

- At beginning, the child threads run in unlimited loop, in the loop they wait for the START signal from controller. If they awake by the signal from controller, they will do send/recv process. After signalling, controller will wait for Stop signals from child threads.
- After finishing send/recv, each of them will send a Stop signal to controller. If controller receive enough STop signals (8 Stop signals of 8 child threads). It will copy data, then start the process again (next loop).

For this purpose, I start my software at a very basic step: controller thread and one child thread, and this child thread does not do anything. (I will move on if everything works fine):

- In other words, controller send START signal to child thread while child thread is waiting for it.
- Right after receiving the START signal, child thread sends back the STOP signal.

I execute this software 1000 times first, sometimes it works well, sometimes no, it freezes usually.

I am wondering why this happens.

For better explanation, please refer my code:

```
#include "CxxUtilities/CxxUtilities.hh"
using namespace std;
CxxUtilities::Condition StartSignal;
CxxUtilities::Condition StopSignal;

// declare a class of tx_thread, open, alive, wait for signal from controller thread //
class ChildThread: public CxxUtilities::StoppableThread{
public:
  void run(){
    cout << "started tx_thread" << endl;
        while(!stopped){

      /* wait for signal from main thread */
      cout << "sub:wait for main...";
      StartSignal.wait();
      cout << "sub:done, \n";

      /* signal to main thread */
      StopSignal.signal();     
      cout << "sub:signal sent, \n";
    }

  }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace CxxUtilities;
    int i;
    int Events = atoi(argv[1]);

    // declear threads //
    ReadingThread* thread[20];
    thread[0] = new ReadingThread;
    thread[0]->start();
    usleep(1000);

    for (i=0; i<Events; i++){
      cout << "\nevent#" << i+1 << ", ";
      /* send start signal to sub thread */
      StartSignal.broadcast();
      cout << "main:signal sent, \n";

      /* wait for stop signal from sub thread */
       cout << "main:wait for sub ...";
      StopSignal.wait();      
      cout << "main:done, \n";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

If I modify this software to only controller signals to child thread or child thread only signals to controller, it works fine.
Do you have any idead about why thread freeze when we use 2 signals from 2 trheads ?

In this software, there are 2 header files are used is [Thread.hh](https://github.com/yuasatakayuki/CxxUtilities/blob/master/includes/CxxUtilities/Thread.hh) and [Condition.hh](https://github.com/yuasatakayuki/CxxUtilities/blob/master/includes/CxxUtilities/Condition.hh)

Here is a part of singal() and wait() in Condition.hh header file:

```
   void signal(){
    mutex.lock();
    pthread_cond_signal(&condition);
    mutex.unlock();

    void wait(){
    mutex.lock();
    pthread_cond_wait(&condition,mutex.getPthread_Mutex_T());
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's freezing because of a deadlock.  One way this could happen is if main call `StopSignal.wait`, and locks the mutex, before the condition is set.  Then your child thread calls `StopSignal.signal`, which blocks waiting for the mutex.  So both threads are blocked waiting for action from the other.

Locks should be acquired for the shortest amount of time.  Executing a wait while owning a lock is asking for trouble.  You need to restructure that so the wait is without the lock.  Something like

```
for (;;) {
    mutex.lock();
    bool done = /*check condition variable*/;
    mutex.unlock();
    if (done) break;
    sleep(1);
}
```

This will keep the lock while you're accessing the protected condition variable, then free it (allowing the other thread access to condition) while you check the result of the condition.  The sleep is there to free up CPU resources.

This isn't the only way to solve the problem but is pretty simple to implement.

Comment: sorry, I am confused with your explanation ... Let's me explain with my understanding: 
- The main thread blocks the mutex to call wait() before the child thread  calls signal()?
- And because of that, the mutex is locked in main thread, the child thread cannot lock the mutex to call signal()?

Comment: @KhảiBùiTuấn That's right.  Since the main thread has acquired the mutex, the child thread blocks on (waits for) the mutex.

Comment: Dear @1201ProgramAlarm, do you mean that we have to signal() before wait() ? if that, I think it is not make sense right ? It is also mentioned in here [link](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables ) **It is a logical error to call pthread_cond_signal() before calling pthread_cond_wait().**

Comment: Dear, right now, I am really confused, sorry, but I think about your comment maybe right. But maybe I also have some misunderstanding. Say, to call wait() and signal(), we must call mutex.lock() first. But if the wait() happen before that, the mutex is not unlock(), so the signal() cannot happen. But we also have to call wait() before call signal() right?

Comment: Dear, I found the answer for previous comment **pthread_cond_wait() blocks the calling thread until the specified condition is signalled. This routine should be called while mutex is locked, and it will automatically release the mutex while it waits. After signal is received and thread is awakened, mutex will be automatically locked for use by the thread. The programmer is then responsible for unlocking mutex when the thread is finished with it.**